# Unix timestamp is different in two computers

Tags: python, unix

I just tried to run the same python code on two computers. The code says:

```
import time
print time.time()
```

I started the execution in both computers with a click with both of my fingers (I accept a difference of up to 80ms), and both codes executed immediately (I saw no delay in execution)

One of the consoles says time X, and the other says X-3. (seconds! 3 seconds difference)

How is such thing possible? I believed that UNIX timestamp is accurate in all computers to the Millisecond...

Comment: Timestamp will be calculated by current date-time on that machine. Check your current time in both of the computers.

Comment: [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91641/how-to-force-the-time-and-date-settings-to-refresh-from-the-internet?noredirect=1&lq=1) try that answer on both computers to sync the time, and then try again.

Comment: One of the computers must be further west than the other. Align them dead north-south of each other and the difference should disappear. Be sure to use true north, not magnetic.

Comment: Are both computers running NTP or SNTP daemons, and setting their clocks to the same master time source?  If not, 3 seconds isn't surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Intern clocks of your computers are probably simply set at different times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize your clocks, if not there is no possible such accuracy. Clocks naturally drift for many reasons. You can simply synchronize the clocks if your computers are on the internet by using `ntp`. There is a lot of `ntp` servers around the world. This usually synchronizes your clocks tightly.